# Configure spring boot multi module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to have a root project configured with gradle, and module configured with maven?

Comment: Why would you want to mix Gradle and Maven? Both are build tools that can mostly do the same thing. You can use Gradle to upload to Maven Central if that's why you wanted to use Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Use maven create a parent project. Update the pom.xml set

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Select the project and then create a new model extends the parent project.